# Convert DOC to PDF, Error: "Does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point"

Tags: c#, pdf, doc

I was trying to use this code to convert doc file to pdf. I get this error "Does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point"
I'm not sure what is wrong with this code. Thank you for any help.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication4
{
public class translate
{
    private static void ConvertWordFileToPdf(string WordFilesLocation, string PdfFilesLocation)
    {
        Document doc = null;
        // C# doesn't have optional arguments so we'll need a dummy value
        object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application word = null;

        try
        {
            // Create a new Microsoft Word application object
            word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

            // Get list of Word files in specified directory
            DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(WordFilesLocation);

            FileInfo[] wordFiles = dirInfo.GetFiles("*.doc");

            if (wordFiles.Length > 0)
            {
                word.Visible = false;
                word.ScreenUpdating = false;
                string sourceFile = "";
                string destinationFile = "";
                try
                {
                    foreach (FileInfo wordFile in wordFiles)
                    {
                        // Cast as Object for word Open method
                        Object filename = (Object)wordFile.FullName;

                        sourceFile = wordFile.Name;
                        destinationFile = "";

                        // Use the dummy value as a placeholder for optional arguments
                        doc = word.Documents.Open(ref filename, ref oMissing,
                            ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                            ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                            ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
                        doc.Activate();
                        object outputFileName = null;

                        if (wordFile.FullName.ToUpper().Contains(".DOCX"))
                        {
                            outputFileName = wordFile.FullName.Replace(".docx", ".pdf");
                            destinationFile = sourceFile.Replace(".docx", ".pdf");

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            outputFileName = wordFile.FullName.Replace(".doc", ".pdf");
                            destinationFile = sourceFile.Replace(".doc", ".pdf");
                        }

                        sourceFile = WordFilesLocation + "\\" + destinationFile;
                        destinationFile = PdfFilesLocation + "\\" + destinationFile;

                        object fileFormat = WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF;

                        // Save document into PDF Format
                        doc.SaveAs(ref outputFileName,
                            ref fileFormat, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                            ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                            ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                            ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);

                        // Close the Word document, but leave the Word application open.
                        // doc has to be cast to type _Document so that it will find the
                        // correct Close method.
                        object saveChanges = WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges;
                        ((_Document)doc).Close(ref saveChanges, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
                        doc = null;

                        //there is options to save file in particular location, default is the current folder.
                        // So move or replace a file to a new location explicitly
                        if (System.IO.File.Exists(destinationFile))
                        {
                            System.IO.File.Replace(sourceFile, destinationFile, null);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.IO.File.Move(sourceFile, destinationFile);
                        }

                        Console.WriteLine("Success:" + "SourceFile-" + outputFileName.ToString() + " DestinationFile-" + destinationFile);

                    }

                    // word has to be cast to type _Application so that it will find
                    // the correct Quit method.
                    ((_Application)word).Quit(ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
                    word = null;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //individual file exception, do not stop but display the error
                    //Log this if needed
                    Console.WriteLine("Fail:" + "SourceFile-" + sourceFile + "  DestinationFile-" + destinationFile + "#Error-" + ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error occured while processing");
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (doc != null)
            {
                ((_Document)doc).Close(ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
                doc = null;

            }
            if (word != null)
            {
                ((_Application)word).Quit(ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
                word = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Do you have *just* this code in your application ? From the namespace it sound like a WinForm project. You should have a Form in your application which is using this code. Make sure your project startup object is set to use that form. Right click on Project and go to properties, under build you will find the start up project. Every executable in .Net requires a Main method, in case of WinForm it will be inside program.cs file, and your Main will be calling the Form class.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with dabron regarding your need of a Main static method.

I assume you have added your 'translate' class to a Windows Forms Project since you are using the System.Windows.Forms namespace.

When you create a Win Forms project on VS2010 you will find a CS file named program.cs which should include a class like this:

```
static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

If you dont have one you can create a new Win Forms project, add your class file to it.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Every application needs an entry point where code execution will begin. C# console applications look for a static function called `Main`.

So assuming that you are trying to build a console application, you would need to add another class like below. (NOTE: This is passing on the first two arguments from the command line without doing any validation.)

`namespace WindowsFormsApplication4
{
    public static class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            translate.ConvertWordFileToPdf(args[0], args[1]);
        }
    }
}`

Comment: I didn't think about the name of your namespace. So the assumption that you are creating a console application is probably incorrect.